# What are the two symbols on top of the tower on the Charles Bridge in Prague?

Tags: symbols

What are called the two symbols of (probably) rotating Sun located on the top of the tower on the [Charles Bridge in Prague on the Old Town side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Town_Bridge_Tower)? Each of them is depicted to rotate in different direction.

photo:

[image]

alternative viewing angle:

[image]

The [pictures](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Starom%C4%9Bstsk%C3%A1_mosteck%C3%A1_v%C4%9B%C5%BE) on [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Old_Town_Bridge_Tower_%288341896176%29.jpg) may be clearer…

Comment: It appears you are on locality? Then ["To find out more about the astronomical and astrological symbolism of Charles Bridge and the bridge tower visit the small exhibition on the 1st floor of the tower. "](https://www.welcometoprague.eu/old-town-bridge-tower) and perhaps write a self-answer? (Incl the magical palindromes 135797531 & Signa te, signa, temere me tangis et angis)

Comment: I may try that later. For now: 135797531 = when they have started to build the Charles Bridge: year 1357, day 9, month 7, at 5:31. There is even a museum on the Old Town side.

Comment: The symbols ae not rotating in different directions, they have spiral lines pointing in  different directions.  Thank you for adding the lower picture which makes them easier to see.